# CMSs not sending emails (but php mail works)

Tags: php, email

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 VPS with a few sites.

If I run `php -r "mail('mytest@emailaddress.org, 'test', 'test');"` this gets delivered, but I have a couple of CMSs (Drupal and dokuwiki) that don't send any emails, including basic password reminder/registration.

I have checked and I am not blacklisted. Where should I look to start debugging ?

Edit: it seems the problem is that I have the incoming emails using a third party while postfix try to deliver the email locally (maybe looking at the alias file?).

How can I force postfix to NOT try to deliver the email locally ?

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to remove `$mydomain` (or `myownservername.xxx` if set explicitly) from `mydestination` variable in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`.

Found it in [this post on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/249561/configure-postfix-to-use-external-mx-servers-for-delivery-of-local-mail-if-user?newreg=418587ca2fe940d0b139d4194bea7fd7).